# Get dictionary key of view being panned and add it to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a bunch of UIImageViews in an NSMutableDictionary.

My imageview creation method:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    char a = 'a';
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%d", a, i];
    alphabetVowelA = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(39, 104, 70, 70)];
    [alphabetVowelA setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
    alphabetVowelA.tag = i;
    [alphabetVowelA setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:alphabetVowelA];
    [letterDictionary setObject:alphabetVowelA forKey:key]; //Adds the letter a UIImageView to dictionary with key: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5. 
    [self.view addSubview:alphabetVowelA];
    [alphabetVowelA release];
}
```

Here is my pan gesture method.

```
- (void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:piece];


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];

        CGRect startingPointFrame = CGRectMake(245, 428, 31, 20);
        [startingPoint setFrame:startingPointFrame];

        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    }


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        pannedPieces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [pannedPieces addObject:piece];


        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [pannedPieces objectEnumerator];
        id element;

        NSUInteger arrayCount = [pannedPieces count];

        while(element = [enumerator nextObject])
        {
            NSUInteger i = [pannedPieces indexOfObject:element];
            NSLog(@"%@ \n @index %i \n Array Count: %i",element, i, arrayCount);
        }
}
```

I'm trying to add the views that were panned and dropped to an NSMutableArray so that I can work with those views independently of all my other views. When doing it with my above code, it seems that every piece that is panned doesn't add itself to the end of the array, it only places it at index 0 every time. So my @index prints 0, and Array Count prints 1 no matter how many of the views I've panned.

Instead of just adding the "piece" that was panned, how can I get the dictionary key of the UIImageView being panned, so that I can add it to the array by key?

I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
pannedPieces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

overwrites `pannedPieces` with a new array every time you enter that branch (and probably also leaks). If you want to collect more pieces, don't use a new array and just add to the existing one.

To get the key(s) for an object from a dictionary use [`-allKeysForObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BABDIABF).

Comment: Son of a.. Duh. Hehe. Thank you! I am still really curious as to how I would get the key from my dictionary of an image being panned or that was panned. Could you or someone give me an idea of how I could do that?